# Calling a function n times with two parameters

Tags: python

This is my first time around, so i would appreciate your patience with what might appear as a lame looking question :)

I'm trying to write a function called `do_n` that takes a function object and a number, `n`, as arguments and then call the given function `n` times. Here's the code:

```
def name():
    print 'Jack'

def do_n(fo, x):
    if x <= 0:
        return
    print fo
    (fo, x-1)
```

When making a function call from within main:

```
do_n(name, 3)
```

I get the following outcome:

```
<function name at 0x01F93AF0>
```

I'm trying to get the program to print out:

```
Jack
Jack
Jack
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This question comes from 'Think Python' by Allen B. Downey. The question and its context can be found at:
http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython006.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are neither calling the function, nor are you actually doing the recursive call.  Corrected version:

```
def name():
    print 'Jack'

def do_n(fo, x):
    if x <= 0:
        return
    fo()
    do_n(fo, x - 1)
```

To call a function `n` times, you'd usually use a for loop instead of tail recursion in Python:

```
for dummy in range(10):
    name()
```

Comment: @user1932405: That's why it's called `dummy`.  I actually think it's perfectly readable.  You could do stuff like `map(apply, repeat(name, 10))` (Python 2.x, `repeat` from `itertools`) to avoid excplicitly mentioning the counter variable.  Of course this would create an internal counter variable anyway, and also a useless list of return values.  To be honest, I never came across a use case for simply calling a parameterless function 10 times, so all this might be a bit academic anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are first-class objects in Python.

```
fo()
```